# Route order in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a route without success.
I have the default rout. It server urls like- http://server.com/Controller/Action (URL1)
But I need also to add this url:  http://server.com/BlueTheme/Controller/Action (URL2)
I'm checking the parameters on the request and adding special theme for the user.
I know how route config order works so below what I configured, but when using URL1, it appears that first route worked. this is strange please help.

***Update***
Url.Action("Action","Controller") generates "BlueTheme/Controller/Action" (When I used URL1)
That what made me say "it appears hat first route worked". somebody knows why it happening and what should I do?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Other Theme",
    url: "BlueTheme/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", HttpRoute = true }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", HttpRoute = true }
);
```

Comment: Try moving your BlueTheme route declaration below your default

Comment: What does "it appears that first route worked" mean exactly? How do you determine what route was matched?

Comment: I believe Url.Action() finds the first possible route that would send a user to the correct `Controller` and `Action`. Your BlueTheme one is listed first, and it does indeed suffice to send a user to that `Action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of your routes look fine, but I would suppose you want

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Other Theme",
    url: "BlueTheme/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", theme = "BlueTheme", HttpRoute = true }
);
```

Notice that I have added the `theme` route value, which the rest of your application can then access:

```
public ActionResult Index(string theme){ ... }
```

Instead of embedding "BlueTheme" in the url itself, using a constraint might be a little more elegant:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Other Theme",
    url: "{theme}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", theme = "BlueTheme", HttpRoute = true },
    constraints: new { theme = "BlueTheme|BlackTheme|WhiteTheme" }
);
```

Comment: Adding constraints, made the trick to Url.Action()  (See update) and this solved my problem.